# Converting SQL Server HashBytes varbinary to Bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash

I have seen several blogs that show how to convert the result from HashBytes to a bigint when generating a hash for a set of values. This seems really common in data warehousing.  This has the advantage storing the hash as an integer which is great for joins and provides for good partition distribution.

I'm wondering though, if this is a good practice.  It has been brought to my attention that using Sha1 with HashBytes produces a 16 byte result.  Since bigint is an 8 byte data type, wouldn't this result in having to truncate the 16 bytes down 8 before converting it to the bigint?  If so, this seems like it would increase the possibility of collisions.

We have been converting our varbinary hashes to bigint for quite some time and have yet to encounter a collision, but it certainly seems like dumb luck if the assumptions above are true.

To test this I tried converting some hashes to see if I can get back to the original hash from the bigint, but was unable to do so which may be an indication of the problem (or I'm doing the conversion incorrectly).

Do any of your math gurus have any thoughts on this?
Thanks in advance!

```
DECLARE @value varchar(5) = '12345'
DECLARE @hash varbinary(max) = hashbytes('SHA1', @Value)

SELECT @hash AS OriginalHash
SELECT CAST(@hash as nvarchar(max)) AS StringHash
SELECT CAST(CAST(@hash as nvarchar(max)) as varbinary(max)) AS StringBackToOriginalHash
SELECT CAST(@hash as bigint) AS BigIntHash
SELECT CAST(CAST(@hash as bigint) as varbinary(max)) AS BigIntBackToOriginalHash
```

With the recent indication from SQL 2016 that they are going to deprecate the older hashing algorithms, we will end up having to use Sha2_256 and Sha2_512 which are longer hashes which will take up quite a bit more space.  This would also be another reason why the use of bigint would be great if it was as collision resistant as the old Sha1 hashes.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think I may have come across the answer in this article.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2005/09/16/using-hashing-to-obscure-sensitive-data/

*2)  Using a bigint built from a truncated hash may create an unacceptable risk of a hash collision if you are working with millions of SSN values.  The likelihood of a hash collision can be computed using the estimate that there is a 50% chance of a collision given 2^(#bits/2) input values.  For the bigint computed using 7 bytes, that means that there is a 50% chance of a collision if you hash 2^28 different values – or 268 million different SSNs.   So if your universe of input values is large, you may want to use the full hash string, or convert a longer substring of the hash to a Decimal value.*

Answer (score 0):

the number of bytes returned by hashbytes function exceeds 8 bytes, but we can use more than one bigint column to store complete information by hashbytes.

Taking md2 as example, 16 bytes can be stored using two bigint columns. note that second query result equal to 4th query.

```sql
SELECT HASHBYTES('md2 ', '0')

SELECT cast(HASHBYTES('md2 ', '0') as bigint)

SELECT cast( cast(left(HASHBYTES('md2 ', '0'), 8)as varbinary(16)) as bigint)

SELECT cast( cast(right(HASHBYTES('md2 ', '0'), 8)as varbinary(16)) as bigint)
```